# Docker Django can't find static files 404error

Tags: django, docker, path, static

I would like to deploy my website in django to docker. Problem is, when i run docker-compose up, website html is loaded, but static content like css, js, logo, mp3 not. I think that this is because my url. On localhost my website runs correctly, but server has prefix something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/Something. I repaired urls so html files run but my static files in settings.py looks like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

and for example my homepage.html with js and css included (this works on localhost) like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "styles/homepage.css" %}">
    <script src="{% static "scripts/homepage.js" %}"></script>
</head>
```

but when server runs on http://127.0.0.1:8000/Something it show up this error in the command line:

[image]

As you can see, the path must be not http://86.110.225.19/static/styles/homepage.css but 
http://86.110.225.19/SOMETHING/static/styles/homepage.css

How can i fix this? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Change the configuration to:

```
STATIC_URL = '/Something/static/'
```

Comment: That didn't help. I thought that this will be error, but maybe there is something else wrong. I have absolutely no idea. Maybe something wrong with docker?

Answer (score 0):

I find out, what made this error. I added to **settings.py** line:

```
SUB_SITE = '/Something/'
```

and it works! :)